# Check if comments are enabled for a YouTube video

Tags: youtube-api

Using the Youtube V3 api, is it possible to check if comments are enabled/disabled for a video? The [resource representation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource) at for a video doesn't indicate a property that can be used to identify this, but I was wondering if people have used another way to find this out.

Answer (score 2):

I actually came across a way to do this accidentally (via a bug in some of my code for collecting comments), and it's surprisingly simple.

It happens that the JSON objects returned by API v3 on videos with comments disabled don't have a `statistics.commentCount` property.

Thus all you need to do is include `part=statistics` in your request, and check for the `statistics.commentCount` property in the response.

For example, in Python:

```
youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME,
            YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
            developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)

vid_stats = youtube.videos().list(
    part="statistics",
    id=vidId
).execute()

comment_count = vid_stats.get("items")[0].get("statistics").get("commentCount")
```

`comment_count` will get the value `None` if comments are disabled

Answer (score 0):

It was requested in [Public issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/list?can=1&q=API=YouTube) before, but it's not available in API yet.

Answer (score 0):

statistics.commentCount gives null only when we do not any comments and we may or may not have disable comments. if we already have comments and we disable the comments, then it gives the correct comments count. As far now i do not see an option for Checking if comments are enabled for a YouTube video through API.